# Need some clarification on HTML DOCTYPEs

Tags: html, doctype, web-standards

I used PSPad for my WordPress template and just now realized the DOCTYPE was defaulted to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

As FancyBox suggests a proper DOCTYPE, I tried a few of the following as listed here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

My dilemma is that if I change the DOCTYPE now, my website looks worse (things off-center being most common).  I'd appreciate hearing suggestions on how best to proceed.  Is the default PSPad DOCTYPE incorrect and should I have started with one of the "official" ones instead?  Am I better off spending a few days redesigning to match an "official" DOCTYPE?  If I were to use the website in a career portfolio, would I need to be concerned if I leave the DOCTYPE as is?

Just not sure how to proceed from here.  Thanks.

**EDIT:** Ironically, what took the most time to begin with is in attempting to ensure my website looked the same in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, so I'm just going to write a comment. You should *definitely* spend however much time it takes to fix your site to work with a doctype which triggers Standards Mode (such as the HTML5 doctype as suggested in the answers).

Comment: Thank you!  I spent some time tonight and the work was less than I thought.  Turns out that using a proper DOCTYPE helps a ton with cross-browser compatibility.  If only I would have realized this sooner!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to proceed is to switch to a proper, valid doctype. Spend the time to fix the issues that come up, and you'll be setting yourself up for much easier maintenance in the future.

Yes, the default PSPad doctype is incorrect. It is not a valid doctype and is putting the browser into quirks mode.

And yes, if you use it in a portfolio, anyone who knows code would likely dismiss it using the doctype you are currently using.

BTW, going forward I'd use the new HTML5 doctype, it's much simpler...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a [Doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype) (the article you mentioned is a bit outdated, I recommend Wikipedia instead).

The HTML5 doctype is the easiest: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Your page renders differently with a Doctype because the browser changes into standards mode when it sees a Doctype, as opposed to [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Standards mode is the correct way the webpage should be rendered, and is more likely to be consistent across different browsers.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful.  Sorry, wasn't sure who posted first and both replies were similar.

Comment: He posted a bit before I did. If you hover over "yesterday" it'll show the exact date and time.

Comment: I didn't know they did the tooltip for the time, that is helpful. Matt, glad we could help and glad you were able to get your page cleaned up so easily.